# Check a variable with multiple values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a variable in if condition as follows.

```
if(table_block_id == ('customer_details' || 'billing_details' || 'shipping_details')){
    }
```

I know it's the wrong method . Is there any other way to check all values in a single line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A jQuery 'if' condition to check multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597015/a-jquery-if-condition-to-check-multiple-values)

Comment: it's not duplicate. I am having same variable and four values. Please read my question

Comment: It start with *Possible*

Comment: `if(table_block_id == 'customer_details' || table_block_id == 'billing_details' || table_block_id == 'shipping_details')`

Comment: you can also use array based to check the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods you could use. I quite like the following:

```
if(["customer_details", "billing_details", "shipping_details"].includes(table_block_id)){
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks . It's working. You are awesome than the rest of people mentioning duplicate for everything they see

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as EKW suggested in his answer.

However, due to its poor support I would recommend using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead:

```
if(["customer_details", "billing_details", "shipping_details"].indexOf(table_block_id) !== -1){
    // code
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the options in array and use jQuery $.inArray() or javascript indexOf() to search array.

```
var a = 'customer_details';
    arr = ['customer_details', 'billing_details', 'shipping_details'];

    if($.inArray(a, arr) != -1) // With jQuery

        //code
    else
        //code
```

Comment: Ok ,@melvin. Try this solution. If its helpful mark it up.

Comment: Ok. Sure . I will